# Match on interval with wildcard

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching, matching

I have two values, for example:

```
from = XY05*
to = XY55*
```

Then I have a `tbl_dff` that contains a lot of strings.

```
Codes = ["XY05A", "XY56", "XY555", "AT003", "XY55AB", "XY35QA"
              "GA003A", "XY36", "XY100", "XY03",...]
```

I want to use my variables `from` and `to` to see if any of these are in my `Codes` variable.

From the example, I wish to have a match on:

```
"XY05A"
"XY555"
"XY36"
"XY55AB"
"XY35QA"
```

Since it is between `XY05* - XY55*`. The `*` just says, that I do not care what is after.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: and `XY36` is matched since 36 is between 5 and 55?

Comment: why do you want a match on `XY555`, but not on `XY100`?

Comment: @missuse Yeah. so I want to match all between the interval 05-55, that contains XY.

Comment: @Wimpel Because I have the wildcard after XY55*, so I can also match on XY55A. I have changed the example, to show, that I also wish to match on letters as well as numbers after the `* `

Comment: You can always test if string is >= `XY05` and < `XY56`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern: `XY(0[5-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-5]).*`.

`(0[5-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-5])` will match any number between `05` and `55` and any number of any characters after.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WsYecm/4)

Comment: It works, what would I need to change if my `from`  and `to` are changing?

For example: 

`from = weq23*`
`to = weq24* `

Comment: @KaZyKa `weq` replaces `XY`, `(0[5-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-5])$` becomes `2[34]$`, and `05.|55.` would become `23.|24.`. And pattern would become: `weq(2[34]$|23.|24.)`, which can be simplified to `weq2[34].`. But this is sepcial, since there are no numbers between 23 and 24 :)

Comment: @KaZyKa You should accept the answer and optionally upvote, if it solved your problem.

Comment: Turczyn. I just played with your Regex. It doesn't solve, if I have XY55AB, but does for XY55A. After the XY55*, i should have able to match on the string, no matter if it has on extra letter or five. So I must say that it did not solve my problem :(

Comment: Turczyn. Nice :) But it should also work if I have have something between my interval, e.g. `XY23` works fine, but `XY23A...` do not work. Same with `XY35`works but `XY35A...` doesnt work. the `...` is just to say that I don't know how many letters there are after `*` :)

Can you update it, so it works for this, as well? :)

Comment: Turczyn

It matches on the two first, but still need to match on the last for 

`XY53A` `XY27` `XY530` `XY35E3` `XY270` `XY270A` since they are between 05 and 55. Since i am not good with regex, i don't know if it is to complicated to make?

Basically it needs to match with everything between XY05*-XY55*. Would it be easier to say, as long as you are between 05 and 55, then it doesn't matter what there is behind? :)

Comment: @KaZyKa Is current solution correct (I updated answer)? You explanation in question was bit different from the one you gave now.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now :)
Sorry for the different explanation, english is not my first language :/

Answer (score 0):

Can you have `from` and `to` as integers instead of the full strings? That way you can extract the integers from the `Codes` vector, and compare them directly to `from` and `to`:

```
from <- 5
to <- 55

pattern <- "XY([0-9]+).*"

# use regex to extract the integer part of each string
Codes_int <- as.integer( sub( pattern, "\\1", Codes ) )

# return only the `Codes` where the integer is in range
Codes[ Codes_int >= from & Codes_int <= to & grepl( pattern, Codes ) ]
```

Comment: But what if XY codes changes to WEQ f.x.? can I make this as a variable in your `Codes_int <- as.integer( sub( "(asvariable)([0-9]+).*", "\\1", Codes ) )` ?

Comment: Then you change the code to match what you need. See my edit, you can easily move that variable outside if that's easier for you.